# Web Assembly, issue to apply 2000 functions in C++ and JavaScript (with for loop)

Tags: javascript, c++, stack-overflow, webassembly, emcc

The program is showing an issue to send 2000 rows of text to C++ code in Web Assembly
I tried to send all the content together and failed.
I decided to send line by line, it sent only up to 1400

- Maybe there is a better solution to check why it has delays and don't push another function to C++. Maybe it works like async await
- How to check why this error happened, still new in this area, and doesn't knows about debugging and error handling.
- Maybe I have to extend the heap/stack memory for 1 Txt file usage
- Maybe It is possible to transfer big Txt file data as binary.

The problematic code, sending line by line,
javascript:

```
      // content = (long txt file)
      const rows = contents.split('\n');
      // rows.length = 2000
      for (let i = 0; i < row.length ; ++i) 
      {
        Module.set_line(rows[i]);
      }
```

My solution is to sleep every 1000 lines for 2ms.
javascript:

```
      const delay_ns = 2000;
      const divide = 1000;
      const row_length = rows.length;
      const remained_sections = Math.ceil(row_length / divide) - 1;
      let i = 0;
      for (;i < divide && i < row_length ; ++i) 
      {
        Module.set_line(rows[i]);
      }
      for (let j = 0; j < remained_sections; ++j) 
      {
        const newmaxi = divides * j;
        setTimeout(function() {
          for (; i < newmaxi && i < row_lengths ; ++i) 
          {
            Module.set_line(rows[i]);
          }
        }, delay_ns);
```

C++

```
      static std::string text_total{};
      
      void set_line(const std::string& line) 
      { 
          text_total+= line; 
      }

      EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(lines_data_functions) 
      {
          emscripten::function("set_line", &set_line);
      };
```

bash simplified code

```
      emcc main.cpp -o main_wasm.js --emrun --std=c++17 --bind
```